# Rotating an image more then once

Tags: android

I have written some code using eclipse for android application.The following is my  Activity.java class.When I execute my code, the image gets rotated only once and if I click the button again, the image is not  getting rotated and at the same time it is showing me"" 6291456-byte external allocation too large for this process."" error.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView img;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap rotatedBMP;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bharath);


        int w = bmp.getWidth();
        int h = bmp.getHeight();

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(90);

        rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
        img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are rotating the default image again and again not the rortated one and also not releasing the memory thats why facing 6291456-byte external

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues

1. I see that you are trying to decode the same resource every time there is a click. Instead decode the file in 'OnCreate()', which will decode the resource only once and will not need multiple place holders for the decoded data. I think this should remove the memory error. After this, call just the rotation part of the code in your click listener.
2. And since you are using the same base image and trying to rotate the same angle, you will see the same 90 degree rotated image.

Comment: I mean move the code lines, img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bharath); to OnCreate , use 'bmp' to get rotated image. Now you do not need multiple memory buffers to hold repeated decoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` function is pulling the same resource i.e when you rotate your "bharath" image and create a new bitmap with it, it doesn't actually affect the original image. That is why whenever you click your button it picks the original Bharath.

I think you can keep track of rotation i.e for first click rotate it by 90 then on next click by 180 and so and so.

Comment: could u please tell me how to change the original image to the rotated image after the first click

Comment: if you want to rotate this image at some interval then it would be better to use animation instead of creating bitmaps.

Comment: you can use this animation to rotate this image at a particular interval...                                                         <rotate android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="360" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:repeatCount="infinite" android:duration="500"/>

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating the original image to 90 everytime from default thats y it doesnt get rotated everytime....

Try this

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView img;
Bitmap bmp;
Bitmap rotatedBMP;
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bharath);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);

    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();

    mtx.preRotate(90);

    rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
}
```

}

Comment: Dude i am sorry to say but.. This did not help me.. The image is not rotating even i have changed the single line that u have mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Image_rotationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView img;
Button btn;
Bitmap bmp;
int angle = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    bmp = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hourglass);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    angle = angle + 20;
    mtx.preRotate(angle);

    // Rotating Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(), mtx, true);

    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

    img.setImageDrawable(bmd);

}
```

}